# Remove parent from custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've created a new custom post type with WordPress. However, the slug adds the post to a parent, like so:

`http://example.com/UNNCESSARY-PARENT/post-title`

However, I'd like it to create:

`http://example.com/post-title`

Is this possible? This is how I've registered the post type:

```
function create_films() {
  register_post_type( 'films',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Films' ,
        'singular_name' =>  'Films'

      ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag') 
    )
  );

}

add_action( 'init', 'create_films' );
```

And this is the [documentation.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

Comment: I have never seen what `__( 'Films' ),` is. Is it a function ?

Comment: Deleted the brackets now, I copied this example from another source so I didn't know they weren't supposed to be there!

Comment: Yeah, WordPress being WordPress again. Anyway, I think you are better off asking it in the [WordPress.StackExchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) (Another SO sister site)

Comment: You can remove this question now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. You need to use **WordPress action hooks** for this one.

Add this in your themes **functions.php**

```
/**
 * Remove the slug from custom post permalinks. 
 * 
 */
function remove_custom_post_type_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    //check if the post type matches our custom post type
    if ( ! in_array( $post->post_type, array( 'films' ) ) || 'publish' != $post->post_status )
        return $post_link;

    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'remove_custom_post_type_slug', 10, 3 );



/**
 * Hack to have WordPress match postname to any of our public post types
 * All of our public post types can have /post-name/ as the slug, so they better be unique across all posts
 * 
 * Typically core only accounts for posts and pages where the slug is /post-name/
 */
function parse_post_type_request( $query ) {

    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    if ( 2 != count( $query->query )
    || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) )
        return;

    if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'films', 'page' ) );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'parse_post_type_request' );
```

Hope this works for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

In a quick test, I was surprised to find that this works out of the box.
 That is, the canonical URI for a child post still has the parent in the path, but the child post works just as well without it (doesn't 404, doesn't redirect).
 As a result, it should just be a matter of filtering post_type_link to get this to work as you're asking!
 Add this code in your current active theme **functions.php** file 
The following code should do just that:

```
function wpgeek_hierarchies( $post_link, $post ) {
if ( 'service' != $post->post_type )
    return $post_link;

$uri = '';
foreach ( $post->ancestors as $parent ) {
    $uri = get_post( $parent )->post_name . "/" . $uri;
}

return str_replace( $uri, '', $post_link );
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpgeek_hierarchies', 10, 2 );
```